# Extract value with XPath, etree and python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I try to extract a value with XPath, Python and etree. I have no influence on the .xml file I receive and I think it seems to be somehow invalid.

My method already extracts the text node object I want to examine.

```
# This is the tag.
textTag = lastExportTree.xpath("//TEXT_NODE[@PROPERTY = '%s']/TEXT[@ID = '%s']" % (key, id[1]))

# This is a part of the xml. I already have the text node I want to examine.
<TEXT ID="1001" STATE="5" LOCKED="false"><SYSTEMMESSAGE>CALBUY</SYSTEMMESSAGE>Hiho</TEXT>
<TEXT ID="1002" STATE="1" LOCKED="false"/>
<TEXT ID="1003" STATE="5" LOCKED="false">Stack</TEXT>
<TEXT ID="1004" STATE="1" LOCKED="false">Overflow</TEXT>
```

If I want to access the content of ID="1003" I only have to type:

```
print(textTag.text); # Will print 'Stack'
```

But the tag with ID="1001" also includes the SYSTEMMESSAGE Tag.
How can I access the content 'HiHo'? (textTag.text won't work!) Is this invalid xml what I receive?

Thank you a lot for your answer!

Comment: If the xml file is invalid, your xml parser will raise an error when you try to load the document, so that's not the problem. The xpath you show isn't valid and won't select the text node you claim... more accurate code would be helpful!

Comment: Have you looked at the section on Mixed Content in the etree docs?http://effbot.org/zone/element-infoset.htm#mixed-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this problem before as well, and this is what we ended up with. In our case we were interested in finding the text in all the non-script and non-style children of an element.

```
# Just to pre-compile our XPath. This will get all the text from this element from
# each of the child elements that aren't 'script' or 'style'
textXpath = etree.XPath(
    '(.|.//*[not(name()="script")][not(name()="style")])/text()')

# If instead you don't want to include the current element:
# textXpath = etree.XPath(
#   './/*[not(name()="script")][not(name()="style")]/text()')

results = ''.join(textXpath(textTag))
```

It might not be the prettiest chunk of code, but it's what we've resorted to.

Comment: @dan.lecocq - the xpath doesn't quite match the comment. It includes the current element and all descendants (not just children).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are showing us the nodes under lastExportTree, this should do it:

```
lastExportTree.xpath('TEXT[@STATE="5" and @LOCKED="false" and SYSTEMMESSAGE]/text()')[0]
```

That says to find all child nodes named TEXT that have the given STATE and LOCKED attributes and a SYSTEMMESSAGE child element.